# Disabling the function in base class in python

Tags: python, pygame

For example, I have 4 classes. 1 base class called Pet and three derived classes called Dog, Cat and Mouse. If the user chooses dog for example, I would like to disable the move functionality of cat and mouse. How do I go about doing it?

So depending on what the user chooses, the other 2 derived classes move functionality need to be disabled. This selection of the user animal is dynamic.All three animals will be instantiated. But only the animal the user chooses can be moved by the user

Code Example:

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #some code
    def move(self, dx, dy):  
       #some code

class Cat(Pet):

    def __init__(self):
     #some code

class Dog(Pet):

    def __init__(self):
     #some code

class Mouse(Pet):

    def __init__(self):
     #some code
```

Comment: Override it to throw an Exception or display an error message. Otherwise, don't subclass Pet since move is the only function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Each instance is only going to be either a `Dog` or a `Cat` or a `Mouse` - only one `move` method is going to be invoked on each instance, based on what you instantiate.

Comment: I don't quite follow. If the user "chooses" dog, you instantiate an instance of `Dog`, right? How are cat and mouse involved at all at that point? Does the `move` implementation behave differently depending on which subclass is being used?

Comment: @dano all three animals will be instantiated. But only the animal the user chooses can be moved by the user.

Comment: @DominikNeise I can't delete the method because what if the animal is selected the next time the game is played..

Comment: well, how about some bool parameter in `__init__` methods, like "chosen". And in move method simply make if check of this parameter. If true - move freely, if false - do not move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one way you could do this is by setting a class variable on `Pet` which specifies the "active" subclass, and then validate that when `move` is called:

```
class Pet(object):
    active = None

    def move(self, dx, dy):  
        if Pet.active and isinstance(self, Pet.active):
            print("Moving")
        else:
            # You may want to raise an exception here
            print("This pet isn't active!")

    @classmethod
    def set_active(cls, active_pet):
        """ Specify the type of the active pet. """
        cls.active = active_pet

class Cat(Pet):
    pass

class Dog(Pet):
    pass

class Mouse(Pet):
    pass

c = Cat()
d = Dog()
m = Mouse()
Pet.set_active(Cat)
c.move(2,4)
d.move(2,4)
m.move(2,4)
```

Output:

```
Moving
This pet isn't active!
This pet isn't active!
```

When the users chooses an active instance, you would just need to call `Pet.set_active(type_of_pet)`. I'd prefer this over using an instance variable that serves a similar purpose, since you don't have to go through every instance and set `inst.active = False` for all the non-chosen instances, in addition to `inst.active = True` for the chosen instance.

You could also implement this without touching any of the classes here, and put the validation in whatever interface the user actually uses to try to move the instances to begin with.